# Should I use a flat file or subfiles, in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am working on an ASP.NET aspx page that allows the user to first select a network security format, then select a form of security under that, and based on that choice, there may be other choices or no more choices.

If I build it as a flat file (within tsql) It would look like this:

[image]

But, if I break down into separate files, it will look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is it programmatically better to use a single flat file, even if it is hundreds of records long (of course I did not list all possible records in my tables, plus there will be more added later), or is it better to use sub tables?

If I use a flat file, when a line is selected, it is added to the request for access list. If I use sub tables, each line will have a checkbox, that if you select the checkbox, it requests for all related sub table records.

Maybe, I am doing this all wrong and someone has invented the wheel before me.

Comment: Find a book or online tutorial on data normalization.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this can be much simpler than what you have diagrammed above in your model. You basically have two entities you are working with in this flow.

1. NetworkSecurity - (Network Items??)
2. Routes

The NetworkSecurity record contains a code and description and represents a "thing" on the network. Can the "thing" have a route? If so then you define 1..n routes in s separate table for this thing, as you have done above. Of course you can get more complex with  how you "compartmentalize" your network thing and it's "Location" on the network.

My instinct would tell me this is better suited for table storage. You may even want to store your routes/locations in such a way that the ip address, root, drive, path and this and that can be updated at one and only one place. In a flat file, to make a change to say your "Route_Description" you would have to update every record.

Comment: I kind of understand. I chose the word, "Route" because I could not find a more suitable word. It isn't always a route. Sometimes, it is a request for a physical location. Sometimes, it is a network routing. Sometimes, it is an access path within an application. Sometimes, it is a security allowance to control security access. I would rather separate everything into like formats, but I have to follow the directions of the client.

Comment: So what and where are answered by your client. However if "what" has multiple "where"'s then I would tend to lean somewhat relate to that in your coding and your storage. Does the client currently operate off of that flat file?

Comment: No. I am converting their word-of-mouth access requests to an actual application.